# Is it possible to overwrite standard page layout loading method using apex class?

Tags: apex

I need to overwrite and add some logic when loading the standard opportunity page. Therefore I need to overwrite apex logic. If this is possible what is the method should be overwrite?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another **Visualforce** page with **opportunity** standard controller to override Standard Opportunity page and an **[extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm)**. In the extension / controller you may write your custom logic.